# Triangle scatter plot with D3.js

Tags: d3.js

I was trying to create a scatter plot with triangle points following this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3244058). But I got all the triangles locate at the top left corner, which looks so weired.
Can anyone help to fix and explain?

[image: plot picture here]

```
code:
        svg.selectAll(".point")
           .data(data)
           .enter()
           .append("path")
           .attr("class", "point")
           .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("triangle-up"))
           .attr({
            cx: function(d) { return x(d.quality); },
            cy: function(d) { return y(d.Type); },
            r: 8
          })
           .style("fill", function(d){return color(d.Type);});
```

Comment: You can't use `cx` and `cy` for anything other than circles. Use `.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.quality) + "," + y(d.Type) + ")"; })`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Add an answer so I can upvote it and get this off the "unanswered" list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `cx` and `cy` for anything other than circles. Use

```
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.quality) + "," + y(d.Type) + ")"; })
```