# D3JS - Display both circles and triangles in a scatter plot

Tags: javascript, d3.js, web, svg, plot

I have a dataset displayed on a D3JS scatter plot. Basically, points of the dataset are (x, y, category) and I would like to plot "Category A" as orange circles and "Category B" as blue triangles.

[TODAY] colors are ok but all points are circles :

```
[ ... ]
      var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
          .domain(["Category A", "Category B"])
          .range(["#f76800", "#000066"]);

  // draw dots
  svg.selectAll(".dot")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "dot")
      .attr("r", 7)
      .attr("cx", xMap)
      .attr("cy", yMap)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
           return color(d.category);
      ;})
[ ... ]
```

I found this thread [Triangle scatter plot with D3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33881962/triangle-scatter-plot-with-d3-js) so I was trying - with not much success - something like :

```
[ ... ]
      var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
          .domain(["Category A", "Category B"])
          .range(["#f76800", "#000066"]);

  // draw dots
  svg.selectAll(".dot")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append((d.category == "Category A") ? "circle":"path")
      .attr((d.category == "Category A") ? "CIRCLE attr":"TRIANGLE attr")
      .style("fill", function(d) {
           return color(d.category);
      ;})
[ ... ]
```

Is it a reasonable try ?

**EDIT : Attempt**

```
[ ... ]
  svg.selectAll(".dot")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append((d.category == "A") ? "path":"circle")
    .attr((d.category=="A") ? ({"d":d3.svg.symbol().type("triangle-up"), "transform":"translate(" + xMap + "," + yMap + ")"}):({"class":"dot", "r":7, "cx":xMap, "cy":yMap}))
      .style("fill", function(d) {
           return color(d.category);
      ;})
      .style("opacity", .95 )
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) {
            if (d.category == "A") {return 0.95}
            else { return 0 }
      ;})
[ ... ]
```

Result : "ReferenceError : d is undefined" in Firebug console

**Edit 2 - data subset**

May this help : to see the full code, here is the actual website : http://www.foolset.com/SNES.php?Jeu=Whirlo . Note that field "d.category" mentioned here for educational purpose, is in fact "d.site".

Data subset : Data come from a MySQL request, fields include : "prix" (for Y value), "date" (for X value), and "site" i.e. category above. Other fields are irrelevant here. Please find a data subset here : http://www.pastebin.com/khdXCSNx

Comment: what is this **CIRCLE attr** and **Triangle attr** in `.attr((d.category == "Category A") ? "CIRCLE attr":"TRIANGLE attr")`

Comment: This is pseudo code ! "Circle attr" would include cx, cy, r and other circle stuff, and "triangle attr" would include properties necessary for triangles. But I dont know if this is a good start

Comment: If so then i dont find anything wrong in this will work as expected...but why do you say not much success

Comment: can you also give a subset of your data

Comment: @Cyril If it may help to see the full code, here is the actual website :
http://www.foolset.com/SNES.php?Jeu=Whirlo . Note that field "d.category" mentioned here for educational purpose, is in fact "d.site".

Data come from a MySQL request, fields include : "price" (for Y value), "date" (for X value), and "site" i.e. category. Other fields are irrelevant here. I pasted a data subset here for you : http://pastebin.com/khdXCSNx

Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of expressions you need to provide callbacks to `.append()` and `.attr()` much like you did for the call to `.style()`. Because the expressions will get evaluated only once when the functions are called, these will provide constant values for all points. That's why the colors, i.e. `style("fill", function() {})`, are ok, whereas the shapes are not. Furthermore, it's an explanation for the ReferenceError complaining about `d` being `undefined`.

Although the callback will work pretty well for `.append()`, I doubt there is an easy solution for setting the attributes this way.

```
svg.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append(function(d) {     // This needs to be a callback, too.
        var type = d.category == "Category A" ? "circle" : "path";
        // In this case, you need to create and return the DOM element yourself. 
        return document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", type);
      })
      .attr(
        // Not sure, if there is an easy solution to setting the attributes.
      )
      .style("fill", function(d) {    // This one already uses a callback function.
           return color(d.category);   
      ;})
```

Your approach seems to be overly complicated and feels like a dead-end road. I suggest sticking to the example you linked to, which makes use of the `d3.svg.symbol()` path generator which supports both *circles* and *triangles* by setting the [appropriate type](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#symbol_type).

```
svg.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type(function(d) {
        return d.category == "Category A" ? "triangle-up" : "circle";
    }))
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + xMap(d) + "," + yMap(d) + ")";
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works after I corrected two typos. I edited your answer so that I can upovote and validate it.

Comment: @Vincent Did you save your edit? The revision history shows just my initial posting but no further edits.

Comment: Yes I did ! "Thanks for your edit!
This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed. ". I just did it again. Thanks

Comment: @Vincent Ah, of course, the infamous Suggested Edits Queue. If you were able to save another edit, that means your first suggestion was rejected. If this one is turned down as well, you might point the errors out for me to do the edits myself.

Comment: `svg.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type(function(d) {
        return d.category == "Category A" ? "triangle-up" : "circle";
    })) // One more ")"
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + xMap(d) + "," + yMap(d) + ")";
    }); // Missing "(d)"` SOrry for formatting

Comment: @Vincent Agreed, the missing parenthesis was a typo. I have also included the missing `(d)`s, but you should adjust your question accordingly to make it fit the answer ;-) I had just copied `xMap` and `yMap` down from your question where there are no additional `(d)`s ;-) Once this is done, I am going to delete my comments since they are not really helpful to anyone coming across this.